# How to Freeze First Column of WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, freeze, freezable

I have a WPF DataGrid..

I want to freeze first column of that WPF DataGrid while horizontal scrlling..

My code is:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgQuestionTemplate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Width="870" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" IsReadOnly="False">

            <DataGrid.Columns>                    
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ExamDate}" Header="Date" IsReadOnly="True" Width="90" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ExamName}" Header="Test Name" IsReadOnly="True" Width="195" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Batch}" Header="Batch" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ExamTime}" Header="    Count Down  [Days: hr: min: sec]"  IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Set the DataGrid's `FrozenColumnCount="1"`.

```xml
<DataGrid FrozenColumnCount="1" Name="dgQuestionTemplate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Width="870" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" IsReadOnly="False">
```

> Frozen columns are columns that are always displayed and cannot be
> scrolled out of visibility. Frozen columns are always the leftmost
> columns in display order. You cannot drag frozen columns into the
> group of unfrozen columns or drag unfrozen columns into the group of
> frozen columns.

[DataGrid.FrozenColumnCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.frozencolumncount%28VS.95%29.aspx)